# Different behaviour with and without @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

The following code will not produce "Fizz" when the value of `i` is a multiple of 3:

```
@tf.function
def fizzbuzz(n):
  msg = tf.constant('')
  for i in tf.range(n):
    if int(i % 3) == 0:
      msg += 'Fizz'
    elif tf.equal(i % 5, 0):
      msg += 'Buzz'
    else:
      msg += tf.as_string(i)
    msg += '\n'
  return msg

print(fizzbuzz(tf.constant(15)).numpy().decode())
```

But if one comments the `@tf.function` decorator out, it works normally for multiples of 3. How come?

Answer (score 0):

Following fix worked for me: Use a combination of `tf.mod` and `tf.equal` instead of `%` and `==`.

I encountered this problem some days ago and I am not sure, if it's a bug or desired behaviour.

```py
@tf.function
def fizzbuzz(n):
    msg = tf.constant('')
    for i in tf.range(n):
        if tf.equal(tf.mod(i, 3), 0):
            msg += 'Fizz'
        elif tf.equal(i % 5, 0):
            msg += 'Buzz'
        else:
            msg += tf.as_string(i)
        msg += '\n'
    return msg
print(fizzbuzz(tf.constant(15)).numpy().decode())
# Output
#Fizz
#1
#2
#Fizz
#4
#Buzz
#Fizz
#7
#8
#Fizz
#Buzz
#11
#Fizz
#13
#14
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need `tf.mod`: `tf.equal(i % 3, 0)` will work. I'm just wondering if this is a bug.

Comment: I don't think that it is the desired behaviour and you may want to fill an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues to ask the developers